# Why was this answer marked as "not good" in "late answers" review?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Regarding this "late answers" review audit:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4986550

I suggested this answer needs no action and is good "as is".

However, SO failed me on this audit claiming this is a low quality answer of type "link only".

It is true that on first glance the answer seems quite thin and contains mainly a link, however, I **carefully** inspected it and determined that the link is indeed the answer to the question (as suggested by [David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243675/get-list-of-members-of-a-public-group-from-facebook#comment36925849_23967121)).

My questions are therefore,

1. Why was it decided that this answer is a "link only" and of low quality?
2. Why was I failed an audit despite the attention I paid to the reviewing process?

Comment: Because when it went through the VLQ queue before a number of reviewers deemed it to be a link-only answer (plus presumably the downvote adds to that conclusion). They could well be wrong, but thats the answer to question 1.

Comment: @OGHaza - so just becuase VLQ has some "robo-reviewers" I'm banned from reviewing??

Comment: You didn't get banned from 1 failed audit. Yes this audit was unfair - but thats why it takes multiple fails to incur a ban.

Comment: @OGHaza it's not the first dubious audit I came across... I do not always "raise the flag" after each audit...

Answer (score 6):

> Why was it decided that this answer is a "link only" and of low quality?

Because it consists mainly of a link that suggested a third party service. And it contains no content other than that link, it's indeed a low quality answer.

It is effectively "use this third party service" which raises eyebrows since people immediately assume it's an advertisement, especially when it contains no additional content.

> Why was I failed an audit despite the attention I paid to the reviewing process?

It was marginal and you failed it. While you did your job well, where wood is chopped splinters fall, the audit system is not perfect and is generated automatically.

This was a marginal case, while your judgement was perfectly valid, it just happened to disagree with that of other reviewers there.

Don't worry about it, you won't get banned for missing an audit here and there.

Comment: Yeah, this was a spammer. Links promoting third-party services by new users should be examined very carefully. In this case, it was at least the second account by the same person promoting this site in multiple places here.